# How to change the PATH of python?

Tags: python

MY cmd doesn't show that Python is installed and gives me an error

I changed the PATH and it's this--> C:\Users\sewmini\Documents\Python

The error I get is "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: On windows you're supposed to use `py`.

Comment: While installing via installer there will be a checkbox that says "Add python to path variable". Try to uninstall and reinstall it with the official installer. Otherwise, find the location  of python/script and add it to path.

Comment: After change **path** you have to open new cmd to use python.

Comment: You have to find in which directory python.exe is. Then add that directory to PATH. I wouldnt expect it to be in "Documents". It is probably C:\PythonXXX, or C:\Program Files\PythonXXX or C:\Users\...\AppData\LocalPrograms\PythonXXX

Comment: Hello, I reinstalled and changed the PATH and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You must set your PATH to the python executable.

i.e. `'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe'`